# Return value from wxpython main frame

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

i am facing some issues to get return value from wxpython main fram.

my script:

```
import wx

import wx.xrc

class Email_template( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent, to, cc, subject, message_boby ):
        app = wx.App(False)
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 650,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        self.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK ) )

        main_sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer( 0, 1, 0, 0 )
        main_sizer.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        main_sizer.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        header_sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer( 0, 2, 0, 0 )
        header_sizer.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        header_sizer.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        header_sizer_right = wx.FlexGridSizer( 0, 1, 0, 0 )
        header_sizer_right.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        header_sizer_right.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        self.mail_send_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Send", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,50 ), 0 )
        header_sizer_right.Add( self.mail_send_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.mail_edit_button = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Edit", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( -1,50 ), 0 )
        header_sizer_right.Add( self.mail_edit_button, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        header_sizer.Add( header_sizer_right, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        header_sizer_left = wx.FlexGridSizer( 0, 2, 0, 0 )
        header_sizer_left.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        header_sizer_left.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        self.from_staticText = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"From:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.from_staticText.Wrap( -1 )
        header_sizer_left.Add( self.from_staticText, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.from_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, "from_mail@mymail.com", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 400,-1 ), 0 )
        header_sizer_left.Add( self.from_textCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.to_staticText = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"To:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.to_staticText.Wrap( -1 )
        header_sizer_left.Add( self.to_staticText, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.to_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, to, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 400,-1 ), 0 )
        header_sizer_left.Add( self.to_textCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.cc_staticText = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"CC:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.cc_staticText.Wrap( -1 )
        header_sizer_left.Add( self.cc_staticText, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.cc_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, cc, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 400,-1 ), 0 )
        header_sizer_left.Add( self.cc_textCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.subject_staticText = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Subject:", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.subject_staticText.Wrap( -1 )
        header_sizer_left.Add( self.subject_staticText, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.subject_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, subject, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size( 400,-1 ), 0 )
        header_sizer_left.Add( self.subject_textCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        header_sizer.Add( header_sizer_left, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        main_sizer.Add( header_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        mail_sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer( 0, 1, 0, 0 )
        mail_sizer.SetFlexibleDirection( wx.BOTH )
        mail_sizer.SetNonFlexibleGrowMode( wx.FLEX_GROWMODE_SPECIFIED )

        self.mail_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, message_boby, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE, size=( 600,330 ))
        mail_sizer.Add( self.mail_textCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )
        main_sizer.Add( mail_sizer, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.to_textCtrl.Enable(False)
        self.cc_textCtrl.Enable(False)
        self.subject_textCtrl.Enable(False)
        self.mail_textCtrl.Enable(False)
        self.message_boby = message_boby
        self.SetSizer( main_sizer )
        self.Layout()
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, self.mail_send_button.GetId(), self.OnClick_send)
        wx.EVT_BUTTON(self, self.mail_edit_button.GetId(), self.OnClick_edit)
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        self.Show(True)
        app.MainLoop()

    def OnClick_send(self, event):
        self.to = self.to_textCtrl.GetValue()
        self.cc = self.cc_textCtrl.GetValue()
        self.subject = self.subject_textCtrl.GetValue()
        self.message_boby = self.mail_textCtrl.GetValue()
        r_value = self.message_boby
        self.Destroy()
        return r_value

    def OnClick_edit(self, event):
        self.to_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.cc_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.subject_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.mail_textCtrl.Enable(True)

return_values = Email_template(None, "tomail@mymail.com", "cc_copy@mymail.com", "message subject", "mail")
print return_values
```

it showing below error message:

```
wxPython wrapper for DELETED Email_template object! (The C++ object no longer exists.)
```

but i need to print message_body updated content from gui.

Thanks.

Comment: please help me to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, I have changed your sizers. I have replaced them with one `GridBagSizer` which is very powerful. I have also deleted most of the widget size parameters as sizer is now going to handle widget sizes based on window size. I have also removed a lot of parameters from your wx calls, as those are default. By removing default optional parameters, the code is more readable. You mostly do not need `wx.ID_ANY`, `wx.DefaultSize`, `wx.DefaultPosition` or `wx.EmptyString` etc. in `wxPython` as you would in `wxWidgets`.

Second, the way you have programmed your app is weird. I think you want either of the two:

1) **Create an GUI application** which has a window, allows you to edit, does something as you press <kbd>Send</kbd>. It also closes itself when you press <kbd>Send</kbd> in your case, so maybe that is not what you are after...

```
import wx

class EmailTemplate(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, to, cc, subject, message_body):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(650, 500))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)       
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK))

        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        self.sizer.AddGrowableCol(3)
        self.sizer.AddGrowableRow(5)

        # Add spacers. Not the best, but avoids another sizer for border
        self.sizer.Add((0, 0), pos=(0, 4))
        self.sizer.Add((0, 0), pos=(6, 0))

        self.mail_send_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Send")
        self.mail_send_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick_send)
        self.sizer.Add(self.mail_send_button, pos=(1, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.mail_edit_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Edit")
        self.mail_edit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick_edit)
        self.sizer.Add(self.mail_edit_button, pos=(3, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.from_staticText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="From:")
        self.sizer.Add(self.from_staticText, pos=(1, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.from_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="from_mail@mymail.com")
        self.sizer.Add(self.from_textCtrl, pos=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.to_staticText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="To:")
        self.sizer.Add(self.to_staticText, pos=(2, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.to_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value=to)
        self.sizer.Add(self.to_textCtrl, pos=(2, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.cc_staticText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="CC:")
        self.sizer.Add(self.cc_staticText, pos=(3, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.cc_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value=cc)
        self.sizer.Add(self.cc_textCtrl, pos=(3, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.subject_staticText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Subject:")
        self.sizer.Add(self.subject_staticText, pos=(4, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.subject_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value=subject)
        self.sizer.Add(self.subject_textCtrl, pos=(4, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.mail_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value=message_body, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.sizer.Add(self.mail_textCtrl, pos=(5, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        self.to_textCtrl.Disable()
        self.cc_textCtrl.Disable()
        self.subject_textCtrl.Disable()
        self.mail_textCtrl.Disable()

        self.Show()

    def OnClick_send(self, event):
        self.DoSomethingWithEmail(self.to_textCtrl.GetValue(),
                                  self.cc_textCtrl.GetValue(),
                                  self.subject_textCtrl.GetValue(),
                                  self.mail_textCtrl.GetValue())
        self.Close()

    def OnClick_edit(self, event):
        self.to_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.cc_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.subject_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.mail_textCtrl.Enable(True)

    def DoSomethingWithEmail(self, to, cc, subject, text):
        # Maybe send here?
        print to, cc, subject, text

app = wx.App(False)
window = EmailTemplate("tomail@mymail.com", "cc_copy@mymail.com", "message subject", "mail")
app.MainLoop()
```

2) Create just a **Dialog**, show the dialog, have it closed by the user (using <kbd>Send</kbd>) and follow with your Python script without having a real GUI application.

```
import wx

class EmailTemplate(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, to, cc, subject, message_body):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, size=(650, 500))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)       
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.SystemSettings.GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_INFOBK))

        self.main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer()

        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        self.sizer.AddGrowableCol(3)
        self.sizer.AddGrowableRow(5)

        # Add spacers. Not the best, but avoids another sizer for border
        self.sizer.Add((0, 0), pos=(0, 4))
        self.sizer.Add((0, 0), pos=(6, 0))

        self.mail_send_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Send")
        self.mail_send_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick_send)
        self.sizer.Add(self.mail_send_button, pos=(1, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.mail_edit_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Edit")
        self.mail_edit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick_edit)
        self.sizer.Add(self.mail_edit_button, pos=(3, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.from_staticText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="From:")
        self.sizer.Add(self.from_staticText, pos=(1, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.from_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="from_mail@mymail.com")
        self.sizer.Add(self.from_textCtrl, pos=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.to_staticText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="To:")
        self.sizer.Add(self.to_staticText, pos=(2, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.to_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value=to)
        self.sizer.Add(self.to_textCtrl, pos=(2, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.cc_staticText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="CC:")
        self.sizer.Add(self.cc_staticText, pos=(3, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.cc_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value=cc)
        self.sizer.Add(self.cc_textCtrl, pos=(3, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.subject_staticText = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="Subject:")
        self.sizer.Add(self.subject_staticText, pos=(4, 2), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
        self.subject_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value=subject)
        self.sizer.Add(self.subject_textCtrl, pos=(4, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.mail_textCtrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value=message_body, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.sizer.Add(self.mail_textCtrl, pos=(5, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.main_sizer.Add(self.panel, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.main_sizer)

        self.to_textCtrl.Disable()
        self.cc_textCtrl.Disable()
        self.subject_textCtrl.Disable()
        self.mail_textCtrl.Disable()

    def OnClick_send(self, event):
        self.to = self.to_textCtrl.GetValue()
        self.cc = self.cc_textCtrl.GetValue()
        self.subject = self.subject_textCtrl.GetValue()
        self.body = self.mail_textCtrl.GetValue()
        self.EndModal(wx.ID_OK)

    def OnClick_edit(self, event):
        self.to_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.cc_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.subject_textCtrl.Enable(True)
        self.mail_textCtrl.Enable(True)

    def GetValuesAsDict(self):
        d = {"to": self.to,
             "cc": self.cc,
             "subject": self.subject,
             "body": self.body}
        return d

app = wx.App(False)
dialog = EmailTemplate("tomail@mymail.com", "cc_copy@mymail.com", "message subject", "mail")
result = dialog.ShowModal()
if result == wx.ID_OK:
    # Maybe send here instead of print?
    print dialog.GetValuesAsDict()
```

Note the differences of how the code is composed. The difference may be subtle in your case, but will be more significant if you decide to build something bigger. It is also idiomatic way to use wxPython, so other programmers will find it easier to understand your code.